# How to cast parameter of a function to Any in a function given as method's argument?

Tags: ios, swift, function, casting

How to cast parameter of a function to Any in a function given as method's argument?

```
struct InitializationStaticData: Decodable {}

func method1(responseListener: @escaping (_ status:Int, _ data: InitializationStaticData?) -> Void)
{
    let dsa = responseListener as! (Int, Any?) -> Void // EXC_BREAKPOINT
    let asd = responseListener as! (Int, Decodable?) -> Void // EXC_BREAKPOINT
    method2(responseListener: sdd)
}
```

I tried to cast it like this:

```
func method2<T>(responseListener: @escaping (_ status: Int, _ data: Any?) -> Void)
{
}
```

Comment: Upcast to `Any` is always a very bad idea. What are you going to accomplish?

Comment: method2 receives data from the server, parses string into specified type (removed this part as it's irrelevant to the problem) and passes it to the responseListener. method2 is universal method for accessing server, where method1 is for a specific api call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically the generic approach is right.

Change the type of `data` to `T` and constrain the generic to `Decodable`

```
func method2<T : Decodable>(responseListener: @escaping (Int, T) -> Void)
{
}
```

The underscore characters and the parameter labels are Swift 2 legacy, they are unused in Swift 3+

Comment: that helped, god bless stackoverflow